# Return table from method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, return

I have a method that gets all players in a game. The problem is that I want to sort them in two teams. But how can I return a table? I already tried 2D Arrays but I don't know how to put the players at the last position. I also saw the option to use 2D ArrayLists, but this looks very complicated. Is there a elegant way to solve this problem?

EDIT (my current code):

```
public String[][] getGameMembers()
{
    if(!isIngame())
    {
        return null;
    }

    //Return-Array 
    String[][] playerTable = new String[2][6];


    //Get all Players
    List<Participant> l = game.getParticipants();

    //Put each player in the Arraylist
    for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
    {
        Participant s = l.get(i);

        //Get teams and put in the right place in array
        if( l.get(i).getTeam() == Side.BLUE )
        {
            playerTable[0][playerTable.length] = s.getSummonerName() + " (" + s.getChampion() + ")" ;
        }
        else
        {
            playerTable[1][playerTable.length] = s.getSummonerName() + " (" + s.getChampion() + ")" ;
        }
    }

    return playerTable;
}
```

This code doesn't work because I don't know how to put the Elements at last position in the array.

Comment: Where are your codes ?

Comment: You can return a pair, an array with two elements (both lists of players), a map where the key is the team name and the value is a list of players or even your own data structure. Post some code

Comment: ArrayList is the way to go... it's not difficult. Read the `Collections` learning trail and google some `java arraylist examples`

Comment: What exactly (data structure) you get from the method which you called "gets all players in a game"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code slightly. From what I understand your goal was to divide your players into two teams depending on their side (`Blue` and `???` (I assumed red)). The main problem was that you were always inserting outside the bounds of the inner array because of `playerTable.length`. By keeping track of a counter you make sure you always insert on the next empty element.

The code could be improved further by seperating functionality and possible have a smarter way to keep track of the next free element, but this way it's easy to understand.

If I misunderstood be sure to explain what I missed.

```
public String[][] getGameMembers() {
    // Define our array
    String[][] playerTable = new String[2][6];

    if(!isIngame()) {
        return playerTable; // It's better practice to return an empty array rather than null. If an empty array is not allowed then throw an exception.
    }

    int TEAM_BLUE = 0; // Just an easy reminder in order to have more readable code
    int TEAM_RED = 1;

    int teamBlueCounter = 0; // Keep track of the next free element in team blue
    int teamRedCounter = 0; // idem

    //Get all Players
    List<Participant> participants = game.getParticipants();

    //Put each player in the Arraylist
    for(int i = 0; i < participants.size(); i++) {
        Participant participant = participants.get(i);

        String participantName = participant.getSummonerName() + " (" + participant.getChampion() + ")";

        //Get teams and put in the right place in array
        if( participant.getTeam() == Side.BLUE ) {
            playerTable[TEAM_BLUE][teamBlueCounter] = participantName;
            teamBlueCounter++;
        } else {
            playerTable[TEAM_RED][teamRedCounter] = participantName;
            teamRedCounter++;
        }
    }

    return playerTable;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a small syntax thing: In the line `if( participant.getTeam() == Side.BLUE ) {        { ` is the last bracket too much ;)

Comment: @Ananaskirsche You're welcome. Thank you, edited the answer to fix the syntax error.